# how to get match only one username and password in array

Tags: php

```
$data = array(

array(
    'username' => 'bharatbhai@gmail.com',
    'password' => '12345'
),
array(
    'username' => 'test@gmail.com',
    'password' => '8520'
),
array(
    'username' =>'abc@gmail.com',
    'password' => '123123'
)
```

);

**and my condition is here**

> my task is only match one username to one password
> but i got error

```
$check_email = false;
               if(array_search($email,array_column($data,'username')) !== FALSE){
                   $check_email = true;
               }
               $check_pass = false;
               if(array_search($password,array_column($data,'password')) !== FALSE){
                   $check_pass = true;
               }
               if(!empty($check_email) && !empty($check_pass)){
                   echo "<h2>Email and Password matched</h2>";
               }
               else{
                   echo '<h2>Oh no email and password not matched.</h2>';
```

**i am match my condition using array_column funcation.**

Comment: Yes, because you check them separately. If you find the email, then you need to get the password from that specific subarray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your logic which checks if both username and password are same in each sub array. I made quick logic you should apply to your code.

```
<?php 
$email = "bharatbhai@gmail.com";
$password = "12345";
$data = array(
    array(
        'username' => 'bharatbhai@gmail.com',
        'password' => '12345'
    ),
    array(
        'username' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'password' => '8520'
    ),
    array(
        'username' =>'abc@gmail.com',
        'password' => '123123'
    )
    );
$hasSameMailAndPass = false;
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    if($value["username"] == $email and $value["password"] == $password){
        $hasSameMailAndPass = true;
    }
}
if($hasSameMailAndPass){
    echo "<h2>Email and Password matched</h2>";
} else {
    echo '<h2>Oh no email and password not matched.</h2>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can perform a multilevel conditional check.
Actually it seems you search the existancce of the email and of  the password, but not actually for the same user.
Does this email exits? yes or no?
does this passwrod exists? yes or no?

Actually should be the following:
does this email exists? yesr or no?
if yes, does that email fit with this password? yes or no?

So you could check if a user exists and has right credentials

```php
$data = array(

array(
    'username' => 'bharatbhai@gmail.com',
    'password' => '12345'
),
array(
    'username' => 'test@gmail.com',
    'password' => '8520'
),
array(
    'username' =>'abc@gmail.com',
    'password' => '123123'
)
);

/**
* @param array $login array('email'=> 'loginemail', 'password'=> 'loginpwd')
* @return bool
*/
function canBeAuthenticate(array $data, array $login)
{
    $hasMail = false;
    $userIndex = null;

    # check if email exists in system
    # if not, not even check pwd and return false
    # if exites, get ID of user and then check pwd
    foreach ($users as $index => $userData) {
        if ( $userData == $login['email'] ) {
            $hasMail = true;
            $userIndex = $index;
        }
    }
    if (!$hasMail) {
        echo 'Email not in system';
        return false;
    } 
    if ($data[$userIndex]['password'] == $login['password']) {
        echo 'Match';
        return true;
    }
    echo 'wrong password';
    return false;
}
```